# How to create child node in Ogre3D that only follows the parent without rotation?

Tags: ogre3d

I need to create node that will be following parent (with little offset), but it won't rotate with parent. Only always translate to parent's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your looking for **[billboard](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/-Billboard)**?

From Ogre3d wiki:

> A Billboard is a square polygon that is always pointed at the camera. It is also known as a sprite. To make one, you must first make a BillboardSet. Then the billboard can be added to it on a given position. The BillboardSet is a MovableObject and should therefore be added to a SceneNode. The whole procedure is as follows: